# Show that$ |e_n| \leq 2^{-(n+1)}(b_0 - a_0)$

Tags: numerical-methods, lipschitz-functions

I would like to know if someone can shed some light on it.I'm not sure but I think Lipschitz or contraction mapping theorem is involved.

Let $x_n = \frac{a_n + b_n}{2} ,  r=\lim_{n \to \infty }x_n$ and  $e_n =r-x_n$

Here [$a_n,b_n$] with n$\geq$0 denotes that successive intervals that arisein the bisection method when it is applied to a continuos function $f$.

Show that $|e_n| \leq 2^{-(n+1)}(b_0 - a_0)$

Comment: I'm think you could do this by induction using a telescoping sum, although I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you bisect,
you reduce the size of the interval
by a factor of two.
Therefore,
after $n$ bisections,
the size is reduced by
a factor of
$2^n$.

This means that
$b_n-a_n
=\dfrac{b_0-a_0}{2^n}
$.

To get that additional
factor of two,
note that
$x_n$ is in the center of
$[a_n, b_n]$,
so wherever $r$ is,
$|x_n-r|
\le \dfrac{b_n-a_n}{2}
= \dfrac{\frac{b_0-a_0}{2^n}}{2}
= \dfrac{b_0-a_0}{2^{n+1}}
$.